# Backbone - Router not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, routes, coffeescript

I have a rails + backbone project which I have been developing lately. I'm not able to make a call to route method.

My router code:

```
class Pulse.Routers.MainRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes:
    'myroute' : 'myMethod'

  before: (route) =>
    console.log "Before route working"

  after: (route)=>
    console.log "After route working"

  initialize: =>
    console.log "initialize working"

  myMethod: =>
    console.log Backbone.History.started
    # Call is not being transferred here
```

Output:

```
Before route working
initialize working
After route working
```

Whenever the route is clicked which is suppose to redirect to a particular route, a GET call is sent to rails server shown below.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-08-21 10:49:01 +0530
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.slim within layouts/application (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.slim (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.slim (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.slim (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_notice.html.slim (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 69.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms
```

I have been banging my head for two days for the same. Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

Router initialization code

```
window.Pulse =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Routers: {}
  Views: {}
  init: -> 
    Pulse.mainRouter = new Pulse.Routers.MainRouter()
    Backbone.history.start()

$ -> Pulse.init()
```

I just checked. It's working on Opera 12.16 but not on chrome or firefox.

Comment: How is the route triggered ?

Comment: by clicking on a link (a [href]). I can see the browser changes in the url. If clicked on myroute it changes to localhost:3000/#myroute but myMethod is not being called. I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code how your router is initialized

Comment: updated. I'm unable to understand something so trivial.

Comment: Also can you show the `HTML` where this route is triggered.. Or how you are triggering it ?

Comment: `a.block href="#myroute" ="myroute"` just a plan a.href. Browser changes url accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121562/discussion-between-raghunandan-j-and-sushanth).